# Hidding ads on desktop and showing it in mobile view only?

Tags: css, mobile, jquery-mobile, ads, adsense

I have tried to add several codes to the adsense code to make some ads appear only on mobile view and others to appear only on desktop view, but didn't work.

can someone give me a working code to add to the adsense codes to make certain ads appear on mobile only and not on desktop and vice versa?

for example I used this code to hide an ad on desktop but It didn't work:

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 750px) {
.hidead {
display: none !important;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please provide your current solution so that we can help improve it.

Comment: I tried this code to hide ads on desktop and show it only on mobile, but it didn't work: 
<style>
@media (min-width: 750px) {
.hidead {
display: none !important;
}
}
</style>